# How can I configure macOS to mimic the double press spacebar function from iOS?

Tags: macos, keyboard

Using iOS I have grown to love double-pressing the spacebar to enter a full stop / period, especially when using a keyboard with my iPad.

When I enter <kbd>" "</kbd> +  <kbd>" "</kbd> I would like the system to output `". "`

Is there any way I can enable this same option in OS X / macOS?

Answer (score 6):

System Preferences > Keyboard > Text

> Add full stop with double-space

*or*

> Add period with double-space

[image: mac os keyboard double space to period]

I not sure when this was introduced but it is available in macOS Mojave 10.14.

Answer (score 0):

> It can be done, though this workaround doesn't function exactly the same as on an iOS device.
>
> - In "System Preferences" find "Language & Text" and select "Text"
> - Add a new rule where " " (double space) is replaced with ". " (period space).
>
> -Enable "Symbol and Text Substitution"
>
> -Check this new rule
>
> *it works most places, but not everywhere, you need to start typing again for the period to show up in some cases.

Source: http://forums.macrumors.com/threads/auto-correct-in-lion-but-no-double-space-to-period.1225631/#post-16827783

Comment: The original word can't contain spaces. it wont allow me to add the rule.